# Syntax issue in ASP.NET MVC page when using '@' for other purpose

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using thirdparty api to get Instafeed. But when I use the following code in the `index.cshtml` page, it generates an error

```
<div data-is="" data-is-api="APIPATH" data-is-columns="4" 
     data-is-custom-c-s-s="my-instashow" data-is-layout="slider" 
     data-is-limit="20" data-is-responsive="[{'minWidth':1024,'columns':4,'rows':1,'gutter':0}, {'minWidth':768,'columns':4,'rows':2,'gutter':0}, {'minWidth':500,'columns':2,'rows':2,'gutter':0}]" 
     data-is-source="['@hollywood']" style="height:auto; background:none;">
```

Error is mostly due to instagram account name which has `@` sign `data-is-source="['@hollywood']"`; how can I get around this so that I can use the `@` sign in plan HTML code?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
data-is-source="['@@hollywood']"
```